# Can Flink Interval Join shares stream?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to understand IntervalJoin operation on Flink and got a question.

Let's assume we have three streams `A, B` and `C`.
Here, we interval join two streams each like `A-C` and `B-C`.

In java code, it would show like below.

```
    // join stream A and stream C
  SingleOutputStreamOperator<SensorReadingOutput> joined1 = A
            .intervalJoin(C)
            .between(Time.seconds(-1), Time.seconds(0))
            .process(new IntervalJoinFunction());

    // join stream B and stream C
  SingleOutputStreamOperator<SensorReadingOutput> joined2 = B
          .intervalJoin(C)
          .between(Time.seconds(-1), Time.seconds(0))
          .process(new IntervalJoinFunction());
```

As we see, stream `C` is joined twice.
Here, can the stream `C` be shared among two streams `A` and `B`?
That is, does the stream `C` exist as single or duplicated(copy) for each `A` and `B`?

I am confusing because of two points in IntervalJoin operation.

- Every time we call `.process` at last of interval join, we create new IntervalJoinOperator. I think stream `C` would be copied.
- In IntervalJoinOperator, the records are cleaned up using internal timer service that is triggered by the event time based watermark. Stream `A` and `B` would have different watermark and I think it would affect the stream `C`'s retention period, so stream `C` should be copied and managed individually.

However, when I made a test code to see if three streams records with the same key are collected in same task instance, they do.
Anybody knows the fact? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For someone who wonders same question, the answer is 'they don't share the stream'.
Instead, another duplicated stream is created for another IntervalJoin.

I've done some tests to print the buffer's address inside the IntervalJoinOperator.

For `A-C` and `B-C` joining, the same value of record `C` which is joined with `A` and `B` both shows different address.
If the stream is shared, address of record in stream `C` would be same.

I think this is because of two reasons.

- Whenever `.intervalJoin` is called for keyedStream, new IntervalJoinOperator is created and it contains its own buffer. New buffers would be created every time thus sharing the stream does not make sense.
- Also, the watermark of stream `A` and `B` would be different. The watermark decides the retention period of buffers in IntervalJoinOperator, thus sharing the buffer also does not make sense here.